# How to automatically select the taxonomy parent term if child term is selected in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

I have a vocabulary displayed as checklist that has both parent and child terms like:

- Parent 1

  - Child1.1
  - Child1.2
- Parent 2

  - Child2.1
  - Child2.2
  - Child2.3

My requirement is to have the parent term disabled by default. In case user selects any of the child term, the parent gets automatically selected.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Term Reference Tree Widget Module](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) provides a nice interface for selecting terms and gives an options to select the parent term when selecting the child.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the value of the reference field on save. If node entity use [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).
First get the original tid & load it using taxonomy_term_load() to get term object, get parent id from that and replace it in the reference field.